# Need a Horizontal Scroll on Table layout

Tags: android, android-widget

I am having a Table layout which has 3 columns defined. But due to large Text in the second column, the content is going off the screen. So i was trying to place a horizontal Scrollbar. But was unable to do.

I am using Android 1.5 as target.

XML code of the table layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        android:id="@+id/tLayout"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"

        >   
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Name"
                />
            <TextView
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Address"
                />
            <TextView
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Age"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="320px" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linlay" android:layout_width="320px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:background="#000000"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```